# C++ strings and set/get functions

Tags: c++, string

Very new to C++. Could use some help with this assignment on classes.
The assignment requirement is:

> Create a class called CourseList that includes one instance variables—
>   nameOfCollege (type String). Provide a displayMessage member function
>   to welcome the user to the CourseList program. Provide a set function that
>   sets the name of the college, and a get function that retrieves the name of
>   the college. The set function should have one string parameter for the
>   name of the college. Use the function main() to demonstrate class Course’s
>   capabilities.

To demonstrate our understanding of classes, we are to create classes, with objects, with functions. The end result is a console app to view fake classes offered at a fake college.

Currently, my get function is not returning the string with my fake college name. This is what I'm trying to resolve currently. I think my issue is with how I've written my functions or how my objects have been constructed.

Here is my code:

```
// DJ Homework 
// welcome function [done]
// set function w/ college name in parameter [maybe done?]
// get function [not done]
// return string [not done]
// display class list  [not done]


#include <iostream>
#include <string> // program uses C++ standard string class
using namespace std;

// CourseList class definition
class CourseList
{
private:
    // string here
    string nameOfCollege;

public:
    void setCollegeName(string nameOfCollege);
    string getCollegeName();

    void CourseList::mysetCollegeName(string nameOfCollege)
    {
        nameOfCollege = "Smart Peoples University";
    }

    string CourseList::mygetCollegeName()
    {
        return string();
    }     

    // function that displays a welcome message to the CourseList user 
    void displayMessage(string nameOfCollege) const
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the CourseList Program\n\n\n" << "To see the classes offered at " << nameOfCollege << ",type something, then press 'Enter'.";       
    } // end function displayMessage
}; // end class GradeBook  

// function main begins program execution
int main()
{
    string CollegeName; // string of characters to store the college         name
    CourseList myWelcome; // create a CourseList object named myWelcome

    myWelcome.displayMessage(CollegeName);
} // end main
```

So that's my homework and attempt at accomplishing said tasks. Any help with my assignment, or with C++ in general, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at what your mygetCollegeName method is returning. Is that the right variable?

Comment: Why do you have `mysetCollegeName()` as well as `setCollegeName()`? And instead of passing the college name into the `displayMessage()` function shouldn't that print out the member variable `nameOfCollege`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues in this code.

1. You have two pairs of get and set functions with different names; keep one only
2. Since you are defining your functions in the same class, you do not need `CourseList::` before a function name
3. Your get function is returning an empty string, which is of no use; `return nameOfCollege;` will make more sense here
4. Inside your main() function, you are not initializing `CollegeName` so displayMessage() won't display any College Name

Answer (score 2):

It seem that you are very new to programming.
There are several issues in your code and your method is ambiguous. Below is your code after modifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // program uses C++ standard string class
using namespace std;

// CourseList class definition
class CourseList
{
private:
    // string here
    string nameOfCollege;
public:
    void mysetCollegeName()
    {
        nameOfCollege = "Smart Peoples University";
    }
    // function that displays a welcome message to the CourseList user 
    void displayMessage() const
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the CourseList Program\n\n\n"
            << "To see the classes offered at " << nameOfCollege << ", type something, then press 'Enter'.";
    } // end function displayMessage
}; // end class GradeBook  

// function main begins program execution
int main()
{
    string CollegeName; // string of characters to store the college         name
    CourseList myWelcome; // create a CourseList object named myWelcome
    myWelcome.mysetCollegeName();
    myWelcome.displayMessage();
} // end main

// * DJ Tonedeaf *
```

Comment: According to OP, the setCollegeName() should have a string parameter.